# My footer overlap my form step

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

im new in css and bootstrap,

i need help in my project, my footer overlap my container form step
This is my website [a link](http://oceanexplorers.eu/test/apply.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your stylesheet :

```
section{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: #fff;
    height: 135%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: solved my problem , but only on the first tab, when you step into the second "Student Info" , overlap the last's fields. Please see in original template oceanexplorers.eu/apply.html

Comment: You have to increase section height and please check all the next steps and set height accordingly.

Comment: to work in mobile i put height: 1000%, but is not functional, in my all pages is work perfect...
and I think my problem is the wizard form and not in the section

Answer (score 0):

You have so many css related issue because improper plugin uses. OK for solving your footer issue, this can help you

```
section{ 
         height: 100%;
         overflow: hidden;
}
```

Not now but in future when you add more html and css then you can fetch various issues because of improper plugin and css uses. so be careful about that

Comment: solved my problem , but only on the first tab, when you step into the second "Student Info" , overlap the last's fields. Please see in original template http://oceanexplorers.eu/apply.html